# Audio Queue Services - recording

Tags: iphone, audioqueueservices

I'm trying to record an audio stream which is streamed using matt gallagher's audio classes.

So far, I've searched the web as I do not really understand the audio queue services. I'm quite new to iphone programming, and audio queue services is really a complex part of the iphone programming.

I'm stuck on this part of the code :

```
if(AudioQueueNewInput(
&dataFormat,
AudioInputCallback,
self,
CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
0,
&queue) == noErr) { 
}
```

Where should I put this please? Because when I add this in the init, it crashes the program.

```
 AudioQueueStart(queue, NULL);
```

After having tried the steps given on this [page](http://www.iwillapps.com/wordpress/?p=32), I didn't succeed. It doesn't bug, nor produce any file. I expected it to produce and .aiff file.

Help please...

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you need to create an audio queue (and checking to make sure that AudioQueueNewInput worked, e.g. returned a queue) before starting it, the yes.

Try looking at Apple's SpeakHere example app (on developer.apple.com) as a template for using audio queues.

Comment: that example includes C++ and Objective-C++ code. Quite a lot to swallow to learn an API.

Comment: @Yar Seconded. I almost choked just looking at it.

Comment: @Eric yeah I'm currently considering WRAPPING it instead. The idea of wrapping an API in an API just makes me sad. Why can't Apple actually provide examples? And if not, who does?